# How to use the default '_locale' when not set in the URI in Silex?

Tags: php, symfony, internationalization, silex

I want to declare routes like this: `/{_locale}/some/route`, which can be easily done with Silex.

But I also want to automatically have `/some/route` available with the default locale (eg: 'en'), without having to specify it in the request URI. This way, requesting `/some/route` would be the same as requesting `/en/some/route`.

If I remember correctly this problem had been solved for Symfony2, but I couldn't find anything for Silex.

All I know is that I can use `$app['controllers']->assert('_locale', 'en|fr|es')->value('_locale', 'en');` to apply those methods globally. But I still have to declare duplicated routes, and I would also need to modify the 'url_generator' or twig helpers, I think.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I found this as the best solution (Silex 2.0):

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\LocaleServiceProvider());
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\TranslationServiceProvider(), array(
    'locale_fallbacks' => array('en'),
    'locale' => 'en',
));
```

Define the **'locale' => 'en'**. This is the default locale that'll used.

Source: http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/master/providers/translation.html

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [repository](https://github.com/ricardclau/SylviaEstruch-Silex/blob/master/src/controllers.php). You can see how to redirect to a preferred locale.

```
// app.php

$app['config.locales.regexp'] = 'ca|es|en';


// controllers.php

/**
* Index URL, automatic redirect to preferred user locale
*/
$app->get('/', function (Silex\Application $app) {
    $locale = $app['request']->getPreferredLanguage($app['config.locales']);

    return $app->redirect(
        $app['url_generator']->generate('homepage', array('locale' => $locale))
    );
});
```

**Edit:** 
I think the workaround I described above do not solve the problem, it only works for the index URL. But another possible solution would be to set a default locale after the initialization of the application, as discussed in this GitHub [issue](https://github.com/silexphp/Silex/issues/516).

```
$app = new Silex\Application();
$app['locale'] = 'fr';
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to answer this (very old!) question--but can you edit your answer to elaborate on how exactly your answer solves the original poster's problem, perhaps by describing the repository you linked to and what it does?

Comment: I'm still interested in this issue, but this answer doesn't really solve it. I don't want to redirect, I want to show the page right away as I would do in Symfony2.

Answer (score 0):

This question is old, but now you can use `Silex-locale` (https://github.com/pmaxs/silex-locale) to have your route working like this :

```
/some/route
/en/some/route
/fr/some/route
etc.
```

Read the documentation to use it according to your Silex version, but here is how to use it :

**1/ Loading provider**

```
$app->register(new Pmaxs\Silex\Locale\Provider\LocaleServiceProvider(), [
    'locale.locales' => ['en', 'ru', 'es'], // the locales you will use in your website
    'locale.default_locale' => 'en',        // the default locale
    'locale.resolve_by_host' => false,
    'locale.exclude_routes' => ['^_'],
]);
```

**2/ Usage**

```
// will be accessible by urls `/`, `/en/`, `/ru/`, `/es/`
$app->get('/', function (Request $request) use ($app) {
    return new Response('index ' . $request->getLocale());
})->bind('index');

// will be accessible by urls `/test/123`, `/en/test/123`, `/ru/test/123`, `/es/test/123`
$app->get('/test/{var}', function(Request $request) use ($app) {
    return new Response('test ' . $request->getLocale() . ' ' . $request->get('var'));
})->bind('test');
```

You have method to generate URL too, hope it can helps people who have this problem today !